# How consumer a message from celery

Tags: django, celery

I have a few questions about celery.

1 celery contains producer and consumer.

```
  Is the task in celery equals to producer?
  What is the consumer?
```

2 I call a task to send message. How can I consume the message in other places?

Now I have read the docs of celery and rabbitmq. I want to develop a message center with django.
Message center is where user can receive message from other users and system How can I design this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the right approach.

Celery is used to queue/distribute messages which are consumed. Once a message is consumed, it's gone forever.

An example of this is sending documents to a set of printers. Documents are put on the queue. Each printer consumes from the queue when it's available to print. Once it's printed, it "acknowledges" the document which removes it from the queue permanently. If a printer fails to print for some reason (runs out of ink), it tells celery it was unable to process the document. The document is then made available for a different printer to process.

Think of celery as a queue/flow system. Using it for messages might make sense if you've got multiple servers and need to route messages to the appropriate one.

In your case, you want a database table of messages with a `fromId`, `toId`, `message`, `date`, etc...

That way, a user can see the message more than once.